# Limit of a certain multivariable rational function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

When there are some conditions on the power of a rational function, how can we evaluate/prove the non-existence of the limit of the function? Here is a specific example :

> Prove  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}
>  \frac{(x-y)^{p-1}((p-2)x^2+2xy+py^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0$$ if $p>3$.

Is this even solvable?

Comment: I think you need to use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: How should I apply L’hospital’s rule for functions of more than one variable ?

Comment: Maybe one variable at a time, but I'm not sure

Comment: What does $(x-y)^{p-1}$ mean if $x<y?$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The expression is bounded above by

$$ \frac{(|x|+|y|)^{p-1}((p-2)|x|^2+2|x||y|+py^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$

Let $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.$ Use $|x|,|y|\le r$ to finish.